# Well order on $ℚ$ doubt

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, well-orders

I know the set of rational numbers can be well ordered since there exists a bijection from the set of natural numbers and then set of rational numbers by ordering $ℚ$ in this way
[image: 1]

my question is, in this case, is $ℚ$  well ordered by the usual $<$? Same thing with the set of integers If you order them in this way: 0, 1, -1, 2, -2.. in this case the set is well ordered by the relation $<$ right? (Since there exists a bijection with the set of natural numbers)

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is not well-ordered by the usual $<$

Comment: Neither $\Bbb Q$ nor $\Bbb Z$ is well-ordered by the usual $<$ relation: $\Bbb Z^-$ is a non-empty subset of each of them that has no least element.

Comment: My boss is a woman. But your boss is a man. Therefore my boss is a man because yours is.

Comment: @Gae.S.: I think that a more apt analogy would be "You're working in two jobs, the one boss is a man, and the other boss is a woman. Therefore you're working only one job".

Comment: @J. W. Tanner so do I have to say that they are ordered by the order I showed with the picture and the one I wrote for the integers?

Comment: @rukno:  those are well-orderings (unlike the usual $<$)

Comment: @W. Tanner oh thank you! That's what I was looking for, but, one more question please, how can I specify (or define) those orderings (especially the one of the rationals) by a symbol $\preceq$?

Comment: @Matthew Towers what is not a bijection?